# Node js: Executing command line (opening a file)

Tags: node.js, cmd

I am trying to open a file through the command line by using node. I am using child_process.spawn, here is the code

```
var 
    process = require('child_process'),
    cmd = process.spawn('cmd', ['start','tmp.txt'], {cwd: 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\Node_dev'});
```

I am expecting the file `tmp.txt` located in the Node_dev folder to be opened but I am getting the error -

```
dir error { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENONENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn'
```

What am I missing?

Also, what's the difference between `child_process.spawn` vs `child_process.exec` for this?

Comment: Just a nitpick: by doing `var process = ...` you're overriding the global `process` object, which could be dangerous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an explanation for your `ENOENT` error [*update*: turns out this was a red herring], but one problem with your command is that you launch `cmd.exe` without `/c`, meaning that the shell spawned will (a) stay open and (b) actually *ignore* the specified command.

As for how the `child_process` module's methods differ:

`.execFile` and `.exec` take a *callback* that reports a *single, buffered result*, whereas `.spawn` provides *chunked output via events*.
Only `.exec` passes the command to the platform's *default shell*, which makes it more convenient, but less efficient.

In your case, you don't care about output returned from the spawned command, and since you need to involve the shell anyway,`.exec` is the best choice.

On Windows, use of `start` comes with its own pitfalls:

- It is not an executable, but a shell builtin (to put it in Unix terms) - thus, it must be invoked via `cmd.exe`.
- If its 1st argument is a [double-quoted] value with embedded spaces, it is interpreted as a *window title* rather than a filename argument; thus, to robustly pass a filename argument, you must pass an empty window title as the 1st argument.

Here are invocations that should work on Windows - note that both *launch the child process asynchronously* and *ignore any output from it* - all they do is to tell `cmd.exe` to open the specified file as if a user had opened it in Explorer:

- using `.exec`:

```
var cpm = require('child_process');

// With .exec, specify the entire shell command as the 1st argument - it is implicitly
// passed to cmd.exe.
// '""' as the 1st argument to `start` is an empty window title that ensures that any 
// filename argument with embedded spaces isn't mistaken for a window title.
cpm.exec('start "" "tmp.txt"', {cwd: 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\Node_dev'});
```

- using `.execFile` or `.spawn`:

```
// With .spawn or .execFile, specify `cmd` as the 1st argument, and the shell command 
// tokens as an array passed as the 2nd argument.
// Note the /c, which ensures that cmd exits after having executed the specified 
// command.
// '""' as the 1st argument to `start` is an empty window title that ensures that any 
// filename argument with embedded spaces isn't mistaken for a window title.
cpm.spawn('cmd', [ '/c', 'start', '""', 'tmp.txt' ], {cwd: 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\Node_dev'});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue. I have a question about the '/c' command, why wont the text file open if i exclude that, I guess I don't fully understand what you mean by the shell will linger, I assumed it wont just exit after executing the command

Comment: @lboyel: Glad to hear it. `cmd.exe` by default launches a shell that stays open until you explicitly terminate it, typically by running `exit`. If you just want it to _execute a single command_ you pass to it and _exit when done_, you must instruct it to do so with the `/c` option.

Comment: but shouldn't it still work if I exclude that /c option as you said it just wont terminate

Comment: @lboyel: It doesn't work, because `cmd.exe` seemingly ignores the command you pass unless you precede it with `/c`. What happens in your specific case is that when you run your node script from a console window, another shell (`cmd.exe` instance) is simply loaded on top of the existing one, and your file never opens (you'll have to `exit` out of the mistakenly created new shell to return to your original prompt). All that said, it still doesn't explain your original `ENOENT` error.

Comment: i think the ENOENT error might have been a result of a combination of things, including mistakenly including the wrong directory path or just a wrong spawn function call, its gone now, issues is resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a cross-platform module on npm called [`open`](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open) that opens files using the OS's default handler that you could use [as a guide](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open/blob/0c3ad272bfbc163cce8806e64630c623a9cfd8f4/lib/open.js) or just use it as-is.

To do it manually with spawn on Windows though, you'd do something like:

```
var args = ['/s', '/c', 'start', '', 'tmp.txt'],
    opts = { cwd: 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\Node_dev' },
    child = child_process.spawn('cmd.exe', args, opts);
```

`child_process.exec()` is basically a higher-level wrapper for `child_process.spawn()` which buffers output and then passes the buffered stdout and stderr output to a callback.

Comment: tried using start, var cmd = process.spawn('start', ['tmp.txt'], {cwd: 'C:\\Users\\testuser\\Node_dev'}); still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same, here is my command to run and executable with arguments:

```
var exec = require('child_process').spawn;
let scanProcess = exec('cmd', [ '/c', 'start', '""', 'feature.exe --version' ], {cwd: 'command_folder'});
```

I am running this on Azure DevOps in a container running Windows OS.
The above command just doesn't come back, it hangs. Any pointers.